# Prove this equation has no integer solutions: $x^p_{1}+x^p_{2}+\cdots+x^p_{n}+1=(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n})^2$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $ p\equiv2\pmod 3$ be a prime number. Prove that the
equation $x^p_{1}+x^p_{2}+\cdots+x^p_{n}+1=(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n})^2$ has
no integer solutions.

This problem is from the (Problems from the book) chapter 18 Quadratic reciprocity. Because this book problems have no answer. so How to use this methods to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modulo $2$, the LHS is congruent to $x_1 + \cdots + x_n + 1$ while the RHS is congruent to $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding, this answer does *not* use the fact that $p\equiv2\pmod 3$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Very nice!  +1 from me.

Comment: Very nice answer!